# Re-evaluatiing a condition in jscript

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

So I have a little sensor in my 'scene' and when it gets blocked I want my program to wait 4 seconds and if the sensor is still blocked I want it to alert the user.

The script works fine if the sensor remains blocked.

However, if you block the sensor for less than the 4 seconds and then remove the part from the sensor (which should result in no alert since the sensor is no longer blocked) the alert still runs even though the condition is no longer true.

**Can any buddy see what I am doing wrong here?**

The `OnBlocked()` function runs when the sensor is blocked and the `OnCleared()` function runs when the sensor is cleared.

The `OnisBlockedUpdated()` function runs when the isBlocked property is updated.

```js
function OnBlocked( sender : Demo3D.Visuals.PhysicsObject, load : Demo3D.Visuals.Visual )
{
    sender.isBlocked = true;
    sender.PropertiesUpdated();
}

function OnCleared( sender : Demo3D.Visuals.PhysicsObject, load : Demo3D.Visuals.Visual )
{
    sender.isBlocked = false;
    sender.PropertiesUpdated();
}

function OnisBlockedUpdated( sender : Demo3D.Visuals.BoxVisual, value : System.Boolean, oldValue )
{
    var blockingObj : Demo3D.Visuals.BoxVisual = sender.BlockingLoad;

    if (value)
    {   
        print("isBlocked");
        wait(4);
        sender.PropertiesUpdated();
        if(value)
        {
            alert("The object '" + blockingObj + "' is too tall for this bay.");
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    if(!value)
    {
        print("cleared");
        return;
    }   
}
```

Comment: What version of javascript is that? Is that even valid?
Also, there is no wait() method in javascript. If there was it would block any user interaction while doing so. Javascript should be non-blocking.

Comment: Its jscript, and this is not for a website, its 3D object oriented programing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if you block the sensor for less than the 4 seconds and then remove the part from the sensor (which should result in no alert since the sensor is no longer blocked) the alert still runs even though the condition is no longer true

The function is still running while you're doing your `wait()`, and the `value` parameter will be passed in by-value, not by-reference, so it isn't going to change in the middle of the body of the function.

If you want to evaluate that value after the wait has completed, you're going to have to get the *current* value, rather than the value passed into the function.

Try:

```
if (value)
{   
    print("isBlocked");
    wait(4);
    sender.PropertiesUpdated();
    if(sender.isBlocked) // *** This is the line I changed
    {
        // ...
```

Although I'm not sure if `sender` is going to be the same object as in the `OnBlocked` or `OnCleared` function, since it is a different type.  You may need to figure out some way to get a reference to that same `sender : Demo3D.Visuals.PhysicsObject` object.